# Store web address in MySQL and display as link in HTML

Tags: mysql, php

I am a PHP newbie, but I'm making progress. I have made a small mysql database and PHP form that I am using to populate a web page that shows the upcoming gigs for a musician. It shows the date, venue, etc. and works fine.

What I'm trying to add is this: I want to be able to store the web address of the venue in the database and then use that address as the href for and anchor tag that says VENUE INFO. I've called the column maplink and set it up like all my other variables. When I insert the web address in my form it gets recorded to my database as text "maplink" (no quotes) instead of the web address that I entered.

Also the HTML I'm trying to use is

```
<p><a href="<?php echo $maplink ?>">VENUE INFO</a></p>
```

which I'm sure is terribly wrong.

I'm using PHP 5.3.8 and MySQL 5.5.16.  Any help on how to go about this?

Comment: Unfortunately this is more of a programming question and less of a DBA question. You would have much better luck with this on [so]

Comment: As you appear to have identified that the value isn't getting stored correctly it would have been better to post the code to store the value rather than to display it. Although your problem is solved if you post it anyway this question could be of use to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During insert into the database, you may have forgotten to append $ symbol to maplink to make it a variable.

Comment: That was it. I must have overlooked it twenty times! The HTML code works, too - much to my surprise. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Put error_reporting(-1); at the top of the script during development, this will enable notices which help preventing such issues. See php.net/error_reporting for more.